# How to unit test Neo4j in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j

I am just getting started with Neo4j. I am using .net.

Do anyone know what the best way to unit test my development is? Java devs can use the ImpermanentGraphDatabase class for this. Is there a trick that will let me use the same?

Any tips or hard earned experience sharing is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an in memory server that you might want to check out https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-in-memory-server (I've not used it myself).

Or you could run a server solely for executing tests against and clean out the data after each/a set of tests. Check out http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/06/19/neo4j-unit-testing-with-resttest.html as well.